# Xcode autofills my old password

Tags: xcode

Whenever Xcode tries to contact iTunes Connect, I get an error saying that it couldn't log in. I retype my password in Accounts, and it works fine.

But then it all happens again next time.

There's no entry for this in Keychain Manager; Xcode is storing these passwords in some other way.

Has anyone else had this? How can I tell Xcode to remember my new password / forget my old one?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist`?

Comment: Of course it's using the Keychain.

Comment: @trojanfoe I didn't mean Xcode had a non-keychain way of storing passwords, I meant that they're not accessible in the keychain the way, say, web passwords are.

Comment: @egor.zhdan yep, didn't help :(